# Phantomjs not sending cookies when it should

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, phantomjs

I'm using phantomjs, specifically `phantom-prebuilt` in `npm` to view a page being delivered by my node express app, but it is not sending cookies despite being on the same domain.

How can I get phantom to send the cookies properly?

```
var system = require('system');
var page = require('webpage').create();

phantom.addCookie({
    domain: 'domain',
    name: 'ru.sid',
    value: 'aValue'
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(phantom.cookies[0]);
/* This is what is logged
{
    domain: '.domain',
    httponly: false,
    name: 'ru.sid',
    path: '/',
    secure: false,
    value: 'aValue'
}
*/

page.open('domain/anotherPath') //cookie is not sent
```